Yarn start not working, on mac, I tried uninstalling & installing process completely but still giving error
Yarn start not working,
I tried uninstalling & installing process completely but still giving error
wingspro@Mac-Pro resident-connect-mobile % yarn start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/wingspro/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.17.0

